# How do I use the 'can break' option using commands?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I used the following command

```
/give @p diamond_axe 1 0 {Can Destroy:oak}
```

And it said

> - missing '}' line 1, Column 2.

There are no columns though? Why won't it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what version of Minecraft you are using, because the command changes over time.

I assume you want this for the latest version.  In the latest version of vanilla Minecraft, the command is:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_axe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:oak_log"]} 1
```

For more than one block, for example, logs and planks, you can do:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_axe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:oak_log","minecraft:oak_planks"]} 1
```

It is also worth noting that the CanDestroy NBT flag will ONLY work in adventure mode.  If the player is in normal survival, the CanDestroy NBT flag is ignored - the axe will break any wood block as it normally would.

Your command won't work because:

- You have a space between the words Can and Destroy - it should be CanDestroy - one word.
- It appears to be a give command for 1.12.2 or earlier - the zero is a datavalue, which is no longer used
- There is no block called 'oak' - it's oak_log or oak_planks

Older versions would need the following:

**Minecraft 1.8 to 1.12.2:**

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_axe 1 0 {CanDestroy:"log:0"}
```

**Before Minecraft 1.8:**

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_axe 1 0 {CanDestroy:"17:0"}
```

Comment: Incorrect! This question is for Minecraft Bedrock Edition. Your answer only works in Minecraft Java Edition.